# Tooling API Query (FieldDefinition) for null EntityDefinition.NamespacePrefix?

Tags: tooling-api

I need to run a ToolingAPI query of FieldDefinition, where the SObjectName and NamespacePrefix will be passed as parameters.  This isn't working when there is no NamespacePrefix on the object.  Here are some simplified examples I'm testing in Developer Console, but I've also run these queries in Apex and against the API endpoint with the same result.

First, here'a simple query that works and returns 50 rows in my new (empty) scratch org:

```
SELECT NamespacePrefix, DeveloperName, MasterLabel 
  FROM FieldDefinition 
 WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Account'
```

However, if I try to also query for the empty namespace, it fails (returns 0 rows):

```
SELECT NamespacePrefix, DeveloperName, MasterLabel 
  FROM FieldDefinition 
 WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Account'
   AND EntityDefinition.NamespacePrefix = NULL
```

I have also tried `EntityDefinition.NamespacePrefix = ''` with no rows returned.  I have also added `EntityDefinition.NamespacePrefix` to the first query, the value is NULL as I expected.

Is there any way to query for the null NamespacePrefix without simply omitting it from the WHERE clause?  In my actual use case, I'm passing in the values as `:queryParam`s; I'd prefer to avoid having to add/remove the `NamespacePrefix` clause based on the arguments.

Comment: I wonder how salesforce queries for the namespace prefix internally (_I'm sure the platform might need to work based on namespace prefix all the time_) and whether SF support would help in setting up NULL-enabled custom index for this field? In addition to the observations mentioned in my previous comments, `system.debug(<field def namespace prefix field>)` in an apex code outputs literal _null_, which indicates that null  should indeed be a value on this field.

Comment: I suspect that since the `NamespacePrefix` field may (_most possibly_) not be indexed, the query (**with equals to comparison to NULL**) causes a full table scan yielding incorrect result. Not sure if you made these 2 observations: (1) `AND EntityDefinition.NamespacePrefix = '<Valid Namespace here>'` doesn't make any difference to the query result i.e., the query result seems to be based on the first condition only. (2) `AND NamespacePrefix = '<Valid Namespace here>'` or `AND NamespacePrefix != '<Valid Namespace here>'` does make a difference in the query result.

Comment: There is a [twitter thread with the PM for the Metadata Catalog](https://twitter.com/jfrguson/status/1364684070483939328Z). The current suggestion is to raise a support case so they can check or create a known issue. Do you have access to support to do this or an existing case number?